# Upgrade IBus 1.5.11 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS FAIL make ibus-engine-switch

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, keyboard-layout, make, ibus

I need to help my problem. I want to upgrade IBus 1.5.5 ubuntu 14.04 to version 1.5.11 for installing android studio. And I was download IBus from sources. I got problem to installing the package. I was pass checking configure the package but after I compile the package `make` I got the problem fail to make ibus-engine-switch

this is my report log:

> ===========================================
>
> ibus 1.5.11: src/tests/test-suite.log
>
> ===========================================
>
> # TOTAL: 13
>
> # PASS:  12
>
> # SKIP:  0
>
> # XFAIL: 0
>
> # FAIL:  1
>
> # XPASS: 0
>
> # ERROR: 0
>
> .. contents:: :depth: 2
>
> FAIL: ibus-engine-switch
>
> ========================
>
> /ibus/engine-switch/global-engine: 
>   (/home/jboxx/Downloads/ibus-1.5.11/src/tests/.libs/lt-ibus-engine-switch:19711): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 4 was not found when attempting to remove it
>   Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
>   FAIL ibus-engine-switch (exit status: 133)

Please help my problem what can I do?, sorry for my bad english

Comment: So your real goal is install Android studio?

Comment: @xangua ya for a while I change the keyboard input method into `none`